# Parsing the headers of sequence file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, perl

I have a multiple sequence file as

```
>abc|d017961
sequence1......

>cdf|rhtdm9
sequence2......

>ijm|smthr12
sequence3......

>abc|d011wejr
sequence4......

>stg|eethwe77
sequence5......
```

I want to edit the file and want the result file as

```
>abc_ABC__d017961
sequence1......

>cdf_CDF__rhtdm9
sequence2......

>ijm_IJM__smthr12
sequence3......

>abc_ABC__d011wejr
sequence4......

>stg_STG__eethwe77
sequence5......
```

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/19003318/1627296 please don't multi-post

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/>\([^|]*\)|/>\1_\U\1__/'
```

The same with `perl`:

```
perl -pe's/>(.*?)\|/>$1_\U$1__/'
```